# SSIS - Loop Through Active Directory

Tags: ssis

Disclaimer: new to SSIS and Active Directory
I have a need to extract all users within a particular Active Directory (AD) domain and import them into Excel.  I have followed this: https://www.itnota.com/query-ldap-in-visual-studio-ssis/ in order to create my SSIS package. My SQL is:
LDAP://DC=JOHN,DC=JANE,DC=DOE;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=a*));Name,sAMAccountName

As you know there is a 1,000 row limit when pulling from the AD. In my SQL I currently have (name=a*) to test the process and it works. I need to know how to setup a loop with variables to pull all records and import into Excel (or whatever you experts recommend). Also, how do I know what the other field names are that are available to pull?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### How do I see what's in Active Directory

Tool recommendations are off topic for the site but a tool that you can download, no install required, is [AD Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer) It's a MS tool that allows you to view your domain. Highly recommend people that need to see what's in AD use something like this as it shows you your basic structure.

What's my domain controller?

Start -> Command Prompt

Type `set | find /i "userdnsdomain"` and look for USERDNSDOMAIN and put that value in the connect dialog and I save it because I don't want to enter this every time.

[image]

Search/Find and then look yourself up. Here I'm going to find my account by using my `sAMAccountName`

[image]

[image]

The search results show only one user but there could have been multiples since I did a contains relationship.

Double clicking the value in the bottom results section causes the under pane window to update with the details of the search result.

[image]

This is nice because while the right side shows all the properties associated to my account, it's also updated the left pane to navigate to the CN. In my case it's CN=Users but again, it could be something else in your specific environment.

You might discover an interesting categorization for your particular domain. At a very large client, I discovered that my target users were all under a CN
(Canonical Name, I think) so I could use that in my AD query.

There are things you'll see here that you sure would like to bring into a data flow but you won't be able to. Like the `memberOf` that's a complex type and there's no equivalent in the data flow data types for it. I think Integer8 is also something that didn't work.

### Loop the loop

The "trick" here is that we'll need to take advantage of the

The name of the AD provider has changed since I last looked at this. In VS 2017, I see the OLE DB Provider name as "OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Service"

Put in your query and you should get results back. Let that happen so the metadata is set.

An ADO.NET source does not support parameterization as the OLE DB does. However, you can apply an Expression on the Data Flow which surfaces the component and that's what we'll do.

Click out of the Data Flow and back into the Control Flow and right click on the Data Flow and select Properties. In that properties window, find Expressions and click the ellipses `...` Up pops the Property Expressions Editor

[image]

Find the ADO.NET source under Property and in the Expressions section, click the Ellipses.

Here, we'll use your same source query just to prove we're doing the right things

```
"LDAP://DC=JOHN,DC=JANE,DC=DOE;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=" + "a" + "*));Name,sAMAccountName"
```

We're doing string building here so the problem we're left to solve is how we can substitute something for the `"a"` in the above query.

The laziest route would be to

- Create an SSIS variable of type String called `CurrentLetter` and initialize it to `a`
- Update the expression we just created to be `"LDAP://DC=JOHN,DC=JANE,DC=DOE;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=" + @[USer::CurrentLetter] + "*));Name,sAMAccountName"`
- Add a Foreach Loop Container (FELC) to your Control Flow.
- Configure the FELC with an enumerator of "Foreach Item Enumerator"
- Click the Columns...
- Click Add (this results in Column 0 with data type String) so click OK
- Fill the collection with each letter of the alphabet
- In the Variable Mappings tab, assign Variable `User::CurrentLetter` to Index 0
- Click OK

[image]

### Old blog posts on the matter because I like clicks

- https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html
- http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/11/biml-active-directory-ssis-data-source.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  When I add my query to the expression, it creates a validation error in my ADO NET Source of data flow task.  It seems query is now in two places which is confusing things.  Do I need to change my source to OLE DB Source and perhaps a different connection manager as well?  Remember, I built my package exactly per the link I provided in my original post.  Oh and I have not used a FELC.  Do I put my DFT within that container?

Comment: I was able to correct all of the validation errors and the package executes to a point.  When looping thru the alphabet, it fails on letter s.  I believe it is because there are more than 1,000 records.  How do I work around the 1,000 row limit when pulling from the AD?  I have found many articles about this but none are current and do not apply.